How to enable hibernate function on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS using SWAP partition instead of SWAP file?
I've been trying to enable hibernation functionality to my installation of Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and am failing miserably!
I'm running it on an Intel Core i7-7700K with 16GB of RAM and SSD. I'm using a 20GB SWAP partition at the end of my storage unit.
I tried to set my system to hibernate by using sudo systemctl hibernate, but it didn't work and got

Call to Hibernate failed: Sleep verb 'hibernate' is not configured or configuration is not supported by kernel

Then I tried to enable it in the kernel and recompile it, but also didn't work. The compilation broke for a different reason altogether, and I can't figure out why.
Can someone help me out here? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This question is similar to: Hibernate and resume from a swap file. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

My point is that I'm using a SWAP partition, not a file. I'd like to keep using partition, as I've read it is more stable than a partition. I'd like to only switch to file if it is the only way to solve this issue.

My apologies for the confusion. Recently I had a Linux system that created a small swap in zram and that prevented hibernation to partition from working. To rule this out, enter the command sudo blkid | grep swap and paste the output directly in your question above and format the pasted output as code using the {_} icon above the edit window.

This:

Call to Hibernate failed: Sleep verb 'hibernate' is not configured or configuration is not supported by kernel

you get when you have secure boot enabled in bios. Disable it as those 2 do not mix.

Thank you! I'll check if the Secure Boot option is enabled in bios.
